# Objective C question: method won't return a string

Tags: objective-c, pointers, parameters, methods, nsmutablestring

This is my first question so please forgive me if it's obvious.  I learned to program in Pascal a few years ago, so my terminology may be off.  I've looked at a bunch of postings, but nothing seems to address my basic problem.

I have a lookup table that I use to convert decimals back into fractions.  I am calling this method...

```
-(void) convertToFractions:(float *)float2 aString:(NSMutableString *) myString;
```

...with this..

```
[self convertToFractions:&float1 aString:outputFraction];
```

The idea is that `float2` is the decimal that I pass to the method, and `myString` is the fraction returning.

This runs after the lookup:

```
myString = [NSString stringWithString:[[decimalInchArray objectAtIndex:x]objectAtIndex:1]];
NSLog(@"myString = %@",myString);
```

The log shows `myString` is the correct fraction i.e. `myString` is correctly displaying the fraction I want to return, but `outputFraction` is null.

I think it's a pointer issue.  I tried `*myString`, but the compiler throws an error (incompatible types).

Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Jeremy, please format your code when posting. Also, don't forget to select the answer that helped you.

Comment: While all this is fixable, please do yourself a favour and grab a good introduction book in Objective-C.

Comment: BTW: Your string doesn't change because you assign a new one to the passed variable instead of changing its contents.

Comment: @Eiko is right, see a quick overview of a possible way of doing it below. And here's a good reading reference http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you define your outputFraction? Nowhere in the code above you mention it.

At a guess your conversion method is declared as (void) meaning it will not return anything. If you need it to return the result as a NSString declare it like

```
-(NSString*) convertToFractions:(float *)float2 aString:(NSMutableString *) myString;
```

And make sure you return an NSString before reaching the end of the method with

```
return MyNSStringVariable;
```

[EDIT]

I can see you are hoping that outputFraction will be returned by your method but that is not the case with Objective-C (not sure about Pascal). You are simply passing outputFraction as a second variable in your method.

So the "right" way of doing it would be to have a method

```
-(NSString*)convertToFraction:(float*)float2 {
     ...// Do your float to fraction calculation here
     ...// Make sure fraction is formatted as NSString
     return YourFractionVariable;
}
```

Then you can assign the return value to a variable of your choice, for instance:

```
NSString *fraction = [self converToFraction:aFloatNumber];
NSLog (@"fraction is %@", fraction);
```

Cheers,
Rog

Comment: He is presumably obtaining `myString` from the `aString:` parameter for some reason.

Comment: Thanks Rog. This was very helpful.  One thing though.  I found I had to add the & sign in front of aFloatVariable.  Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

You want to change the output of your `convertToFractions` method from `void` to `NSString`.
It's returning null because the return type of your method, is `void`, so it returns nothing.

The return type of an Objective-C method is in the parenthesis, at the beginning of the method name.

Here,s an example, but I don't see where you define `convertToString` so, I'll use pseudocode.

```
- (NSString *) convertToFractions:(float *)float2{
  NSString *fraction = *some code to lookup fraction from table;*
  return fraction;
}

myString = [self convertToFractions:(float *)float2];
```

*EDIT:*

As others have suggested, you should give Objective-C a fresh look. I suggest you read [this Objective-C Primer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/) written by Apple.

Comment: @Moshe By the way, you and I have a mutual friend it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just return the string?

```
- (NSString*)convertToFractions:(float)float {
    //Bla bla do everything
    return [myString autorelease]; //Autorelease is for memory-management
}
```

Btw: You seriously need to read into ObjC. Please don't try to use your old pascal-knowledge on ObjC. It's different, and your knowledge isn't really applicable.

I would recommend buying a book about ObjC or reading some good tutorials for it. (Apple itself has some very good ones)

Comment: Thanks.  The autorelease suggestion is very helpful.

Comment: If you want to read some more into memory management in ObjC, I recommend reading http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to return NSString from your method as others suggested you can pass a pointer to NSString pointer to your function (the same way you pass NSError** to some standard api callsm e.g. in NSFileManager methods). Your code will look something like:

```
NSString *outputFraction;
[self convertToFractions:&float1 aString:&outputFraction];

-(void) convertToFractions:(float *)float2 aString:(NSMutableString **) myString{
  ...
   if (myString)
      *myString = [NSString stringWithString:[[decimalInchArray objectAtIndex:x]objectAtIndex:1]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad.  Double pointers was really confusing me but your example is a real help.